# Get all rows that match another attribute in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have this table (called `posts`):

```
+---------+----------+---------+
| post_id | reply_to | user_id |
+---------+----------+---------+
|       1 |        0 |       1 |
|       2 |        0 |       1 |
|       3 |        2 |       2 |
|       4 |        1 |       3 |
|       5 |        3 |       2 |
+---------+----------+---------+
```

How can I select all posts that are replies to posts where the `user_id = 1`?

The resulting table should look like this:

```
+---------+----------+---------+
| post_id | reply_to | user_id |
+---------+----------+---------+
|       3 |        2 |       2 |
|       4 |        1 |       3 |
+---------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit stupid, but how is your result constructed? I don't see the rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `self Join`

```
SELECT b.post_id,
       b.reply_to,
       b.user_id
FROM   Posts a
       JOIN Posts b
         ON a.post_id = b.reply_to
WHERE  a.user_id = 1
```

Or Use `Exists` Operator

```
SELECT *
FROM   Posts p
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   Posts p1
               WHERE  p1.user_id = 1
                      AND p.reply_to = p1.post_id);
```

Comment: I did something similar to your first one except I used a LEFT JOIN (it's the only join I've ever had to use). Can you explain why a JOIN works in this situation but a LEFT JOIN does not?

Comment: @user4372818 Left join is going bring you all the records from the left table even if there is no match which is not needed here.

Answer (score 1):

here is quick variant:

```
select *
from posts
where reply_to in (select post_id from posts where user_id = 1);
```

so, internal query selects all posts from user, outer query selects all direct replies to these posts